# How to find specific old point-releases of Xubuntu (or any other flavor, I would imagine)

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu

I  have a machine that had been ignored for a while, then had some catastrophe (I'm guessing I caused it, but I'm not sure) and it won't boot -- it gets a kernel panic.  The backups were already stale when this happened.  No excuses, just my bad.

My current plan is to put a matching OS (Xubuntu 20.04.1) on a new partition, and copy over the heavy configuration stuff, then hope that I can upgrade to a modern release.

There's too much configuration in system files (fstab, apache, *rc files, and so on) for me feel confident about installing an OS on top of the existing system.  But if I do it the other way around on an exactly matching OS version, it should go better.

Thing is I can't seem to find an ISO of 20.04.1, just of the latest of the 20.04 releases.

Where can I find it?  Or does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: All ISOs of Ubuntu are handled by the *Ubuntu Release team* which keep only the latest at https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/, with the main products (Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop etc) moved to https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ (when *outdated*), HOWEVER this does **not** occur for community *flavor* ISOs. Some are stored at *unofficial* sites kept by community members, but they're all unofficial.   Officially there is no 20.04.1 ISO for Xubuntu as it's EOL.

Answer (score 1):

All ISOs of Ubuntu are handled by the [*Ubuntu Release team*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseTeam) which keep only the latest at https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/, with the main products (Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop etc) moved to https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ (when *outdated*), HOWEVER this does **not** occur for community *flavor* ISOs. Some are stored at *unofficial* sites kept by community members, but they're all unofficial.

Officially there is no 20.04.1 ISO for Xubuntu as it's EOL (*thus has been dropped*)

---

Another FYI:  The *Ubuntu Release team* won't remove the last Xubuntu ISO (20.04.6) **until** Ubuntu 20.04 LTS reaches EOSS; where normal jobs *move* the Ubuntu ISOs to old-releases (*flavors like Xubuntu get missed*) then the *drop* of other ISOs occur.. thus Xubuntu can still be downloaded at https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/focal/release/ for awhile yet.

The 20.04.6 media is the same as all 20.04 media; except for *updated* packages (*and non revoked uEFI key which applies to prior 20.04 media*) and for *flavors* like Xubuntu the HWE kernel stack is included (*it was GA only for 20.04 & 20.04.1 ISOs*), as per release notes, ie [this](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/) which states

> Unlike previous point releases, 20.04.6 is a refresh of the amd64 installer media after recent key revocations, re-enabling their usage on Secure Boot enabled systems.
>
> Many other security updates for additional high-impact bug fixes are also included, with a focus on maintaining stability and compatibility with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

This media could be used to install a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system with Xfce (ie. Xubuntu), the primary difference being updated packages and HWE kernel stack, which cane be changed anyway as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  (just search for "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel*" which tells you how)

Comment: Ubuntu ISOs could also be used given their actually kept, and then change the installed packages from Ubuntu Server/Desktop to match a Xubuntu desktop; as that can be accomplished via package changes only.